# ¿Cómo calcular correctamente el AUC en un problema de clasificación multiclase?

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

Estoy usando KNN de `sklearn` para un problema de clasificación multiclase. Mi duda está en al cálculo del valor de AUC. El código que estoy empleando no me da error, pero el resultado que obtengo sospecho que puede estar equivocado pues es superior al valor que espero obtener.
Este es mi código:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from scipy.spatial.distance import braycurtis


df_X = pd.read_csv('df_kmers_2.csv')
df_Y = pd.read_csv('Var_Salida_Class.csv')

df_X = df_X.drop(['Unnamed: 0', 'Id'], axis = 1)

df_Y = pd.DataFrame(df_Y.loc[:,['idclass']])

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(df_X, df_Y, random_state=42)
k_number = 3

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = k_number, metric = braycurtis)
knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)
Y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)

acc_score = accuracy_score(Y_test, Y_pred)
print("Acierto de KNN en la partición de test:", acc_score)
print(metrics.classification_report(Y_test,Y_pred))

y_probs = knn.predict_proba(X_test)

#auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(Y_test, y_probs[:, 1])
auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(Y_test, y_probs, multi_class='ovr')
print("La medida AUC para el clasificador %s es %.4f"%(knn.__class__.__name__,auc))
```

Este código lo hice guiándome por un ejemplo de clasificación binaria y la línea que está comentada la cambié por la línea siguiente después de hacer algunas búsquedas. Me gustaría saber si lo estoy haciendo bien. El acierto en la partición de test es de **0.54** y el valor de AUC es de **0.74**. Esta es la salida de mi código:

```
    Acierto de KNN en la partición de test: 0.5439660400242571
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

       1       0.45      0.39      0.42       244
       2       0.61      0.42      0.50       371
       3       0.55      0.88      0.68       626
       4       0.50      0.23      0.32       408

accuracy                           0.54      1649
macro avg      0.53      0.48      0.48      1649
weighted avg   0.54      0.54      0.51      1649

La medida AUC para el clasificador KNeighborsClassifier es 0.7400
```

¡Muchas Gracias!